# Cant use TappedEventArgs in OnTapped Event

Tags: event-handling, maui, gesture-recognition

In all examples regarding Tapping Eventhandling in MAUI I have seen the Handlerfunction gets TappedEventArgs.
-> void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
-> XAML: ...

If I try to do so, Visual Studio says "CS0123 - No overload for "OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" matches the delegate EventHandler".
I have to change it from TappedEventArgs to EventArgs.

No matter if in XAML or C# I always get this result.

What am I doing wrong?
Did I miss any Using xyz?

I need TappedEventArgs or how else can I detect the tapped position?

Please help me.

I need an Eventhandler with TappedEventArgs instead of EventArgs.

I tried casting, but does not work.

Comment: Please post the actual code/XAML you’re using, and format it so that it’s readable

Comment: <Image Source="waterfront.jpg" x:Name="dImage">
 <Image.GestureRecognizers>
 <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped" >  </TapGestureRecognizer>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>

Comment: [edit] your question, don’t just stuff code into a comment

Comment: @ChiefGardener, It should work. I have a quick question. If this is in SomePage.xaml, you have this method inside SomePage.xaml.cs, not in SomeViewModel.cs right? Also, are we talking about .NET 6 or 7?

Comment: @H.A.H. It is inside SomePage.xaml.cs, yes. And it is .Net 6.

Comment: You should have started with this. At 6 you have to cast it. At 7 you do not. Isn't upgrading to .7 an option? Many bugs were fixed. (And are being fixed only in 7)

Comment: I see. You are right. But when I switch in the Docs from 7 to 6 it shows the same Example, using TappedEventArgs. Man, I really would hug and kiss you on a platonic base... I  fucked around with this shit the whole week. I will consider switching to .Net 7, it seems, I have to. Thank you very much for your help.